# AWS Lambda code vanishes, and so does code download option?

Tags: aws-lambda

I've been using AWS Lambda the last month by editing code directly in the inline editor. It worked fine, but today that editor is just absent from the UI. There's no error, there's nothing else missing, there's no options changed, it's just... gone.

I googled this, and some people have the problem when their code became too large -- but those people apparently got an error displayed, and my code is only ~300 lines. Oh well. I figure I'll just use zip files from now on.

The problem is that I can't find any way to view or download my code. 3 SO/Google results said "Use the Actions -> Download Function feature!", but that isn't an option for me. Export Function is, but it only exports either a 600-byte YAML config file or an AWS deployment package, which I can't read. I can't find any way to download my code so I can edit it and re-upload or at least save what I worked on.

Am I missing something? What happened, and why, and what can I do?

Comment: Can you show the screenshot, please?

Comment: Did you source control it?  Also, screenshot

Answer (score 3):

Check whether your AWS region has changed. In case you are on a different as compared to where you had created it, it will not display any lambda function. It sounds trivial, but may be worth a look.

Comment: Man, this worked for us. Had to switch to Ohio. This is the strangest bug.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on your AWS lambda success thus far! I think it's time for you to graduate to a more "software engineery" way of deploying your lambda functions. The online editor is nice for hello-worlds but not much other than that. Manually uploading your lambdas to s3 every time is just as bad, if not worse (hehe).

I'm currently building AWS Lambda functions at work every day, and these are the two ways that I deploy my functions:

1) CI / CD

A really easy way to scaffold out a Lambda function with AWS Codepipeline (for continuous integration) and CodeBuild (as a build server) all set up and ready to go for you is to use [AWS Codestar](https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/codestar). Having continuous deployment is really awesome because then you just push your code to git as usual, and a fresh build created from it will automatically be deployed to your dev environment. Does is get any easier than that? :)

2) Serverless Deploy

I love AWS CodePipeline and having CI / CD for my lambda functions, but man CodePipeline can be very sssslllllooooowwwww sometimes (even slower than manually uploading to s3! haha). Sometimes I need a faster feedback loop and don't feel like waiting for the CI pipeline, and in these cases I'll normally use [serverless framework](https://serverless.com). The term "framework" is a bit misleading since it is a command line tool, not a npm library to install. Basically, you put a `serverless.yml` file in the root of your project, and then when you want to deploy you just go to your command line and type `serverless deploy`.

Hope this helps. Good luck and happy coding!